# Crear un seguimiento (track) de una rama en local a una rama en remoto

Tags: git

Hoy me he bajado una rama del repositorio remoto, y cuando he ido a ver información de las ramas, me he dado cuenta que no se ha creado el seguimiento (track) de la rama en local con la rama del repositorio remoto, y la información se mostraba así:

```
$ git branch -vv
master               58951259 [origin/master] commit1
develop              12345687 [origin/develop] commit2
features/feature-25  12345678 commit3
```

No se ha creadro el seguimiento (track) de la rama. Yo quería tener el seguimiento hecho (pensaba que se hacía solo por defecto), ya que más adelante puedes ver los commits que vas por delante (ahead) y por detrás (behind) de la rama en remoto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tienes una rama en local y quieres hacer un seguimiento (track) de la rama se utiliza el comando:

```
git branch -u <nombre remoto>/<nombre rama remota> <nombre rama local>
```

Ejemplo:

```
git branch -u origin/feature#15 feature#15
```

Cuando te traes una rama del remoto debería hacer el seguimiento solo pero para asegurarse podemos añadir la opción *--track* al traerte la rama:

```
git branch --track nombre-rama origin/branch-name
```

Cuando creas una rama en local y quieres subirla al remoto y que la rama se le haga el seguimiento (trak) podemos hacer el *git push* con la opcioón -u (shortcut de --set-upstream). Se sube y se crea el seguimiento.

```
git push -u origin <nombre-rama>
```